# how to accept only modified alphabits(Å Æ Ø etc) in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application in which i have an editbox,
Where i only wanna accept Upper case letters and some modified chars like Å Æ Ø etc.,
I have done with UPPER case letters.

Comment: InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
         public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                 for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                         if (Character.isUpperCase(source.charAt(i)) ) { 
                                 return ""; 
                         } 
                 }
               int a =Character.MODIFIER_LETTER;
                 return null; 
                 
         }

   
 }; I have added this code for UPPER case

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<EditText android:inputType="text" android:digits="ÅÆØQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM" />
```

You can add other modified symbols also.